# Why am I am getting Unexpected token \

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

```
k ="[{\"id\": 1, \"latitude\": \"52.511467\", \"longitude\": \"13.447179\", \"bearing\": \"0.000000\", \"speed\": \"0.000000\", \"device_status\": 0, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"latitude\": \"53.511467\", \"longitude\": \"14.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 2, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"latitude\": \"54.511467\", \"longitude\": \"15.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 2, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 5, \"latitude\": \"33.511467\", \"longitude\": \"72.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 1, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}]"

R = JSON.parse(k)
```

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token \**

whereas

```
m =JSON.parse("[{\"id\": 2, \"da\": \"1\"}]")
```

is working without error

Comment: Just pasted the code into the console, gave me no error... Ok, can you try to locate the exact location of that token, by reducing the serialized dataset?

Comment: try your code in the console, it works fine. That said, why are you using \" all over the place instead of just using `'` as outer quotes so you don't have to escape all those double quotes?

Comment: @raina77ow Please see this, http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-09-08_02_07_27-aqw0KDLS.1378586275.png

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it is server generated, I am struggling with this for 6 hours.please see this pic http://picpaste.com/pics/Screenshot_from_2013-09-08_02_07_27-aqw0KDLS.1378586275.png

Comment: This was discussed on chat like 4 hours ago!

Comment: changing the "right answer" to another post is fine, but then at least give the answer that I gave you (which I was writing at the same time plalx wrote his) an upvote =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because when it get's returned from the server, the result is getting store as a string, so the string itself contains the `\` escape character before every `"`. It isint valid to escape the `"` character in a JSON string.

It's like doing:

```
var json = '{\\"test\\":\\"test\\"}';
json //"{\"test\":\"test\"}"
JSON.parse(json); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token \
```

However, when you take that string and put it directly in the console, the `\` characters will play their escape role and will not be part of the actual string at the end. Basically, the JSON string produced server-side should not escape the `"` characters.

You could also replace the invalid ecape sequences client-side, but I would not recommend this:

```
JSON.parse(json.replace(/\\"/g, '"'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image from the comments, you didn't tell the whole story in your post. If you do a console.log(k), you will notice it looks nothing like what you see in your console as output by currentTrackData:

```
>>> [{\"id\": 1, \"latitude\": \"52.511467\", \"longitude\": \"13.447179\", \"bearing\": \"0.000000\", \"speed\": \"0.000000\", \"device_status\": 0, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 3, \"latitude\": \"53.511467\", \"longitude\": \"14.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 2, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 4, \"latitude\": \"54.511467\", \"longitude\": \"15.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 2, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}, {\"id\": 5, \"latitude\": \"33.511467\", \"longitude\": \"72.447179\", \"bearing\": \"1.000000\", \"speed\": \"1.000000\", \"device_status\": 1, \"timestamp\": \"2013-08-18 00:00:00\"}]
```

tells us that the string contains `\"`. If you assign that thing to a var,

```
var k = "[{...\"..}]"
console.log(k);
>>> [{..."...}]
```

then you're explicitly solving the problem because those `\"` are turned into `"` in your string. If you pass the output straight into JSON.parse, then there are a million slashes in the input, making it illegal JSON.

If this is server-generated, fix the generator. It shouldn't be escaping that string for you. If you don't have that luxury, then do a string replacement.

```
var u = currentTrackData...;
u = u.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
JSON.parse(u);
```

Comment: what is var u = get ...;

Comment: in this case your `currentTrackData` function